# How to integrate graphql-compose-mongoose with next.js apollo server

Tags: mongoose, graphql, next.js, apollo-server

I am trying to use mongoose, graphql and next.js for my project, but keep getting this error:

```
Error: You try to generate GraphQL Type with name Customer from mongoose model but this type already exists in SchemaComposer. Please choose another type name "composeWithMongoose(model, { name: 'NewTypeName' })", or reuse existed type "schemaComposer.getOTC('TypeName')", or remove type from SchemaComposer before calling composeWithMongoose method "schemaComposer.delete('TypeName')".
```

what I have is simple mongoose schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    }
}, {
    toJSON: {
        transform: function (doc, ret, options) {
            ret.id = ret._id.toString();
            delete ret.__v;
            delete ret._id;
        }
    }
});
```

and separate module that composes gql schema:

```
import {composeMongoose} from "graphql-compose-mongoose";

import { schemaComposer } from 'graphql-compose';

import {Customer} from '../db/models/Customer';

const customizationOptions = {}
const CustomerTC = composeMongoose(Customer, customizationOptions);

schemaComposer.Query.addFields({
    customerById: CustomerTC.mongooseResolvers.findById()
})

console.log("Schema:", schemaComposer.getOTC('Customer'))

const customerSchema = schemaComposer.buildSchema();
export default customerSchema;
```

and the server api module:

```
import {ApolloServer} from 'apollo-server-micro'
import customerSchema from '../../apollo/customer-type-defs';

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: customerSchema,
    context: () => ({})
});

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
}

export default apolloServer.createHandler({path: '/api/graphql'})
```

Can someone please give me a hit on how to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I found the solution is simply checking if the `ObjectTC` already exists and creating only if it doesn't.

```js
function createObjectTC({ model, customizationOptions = {} }}) {
 let ModelTC = null;

 try {
  ModelTC = schemaComposer.getOTC(model.modelName);
 } catch {
  ModelTC = composeWithMongoose(model, customizationOptions);
 }

 return ModelTC;
}


const UserTC =  createObjectTC({ model: User, customizationOptions: {} });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to create a separate backend server with graphql and express. And a front-end server to keep all the built-in advantages provided by the next server engine. The hack is to set an api/graphql endpoint that forwards graphql calls to the backend server.

Here's my api endpoint:

> /api/graphql.js

```
import logger from '../../lib/logger'
import {getSession} from "next-auth/client";


export default async (_req, _res) => {
    // logger.debug("api/graphql: Request body:\n", _req.body)
    const session = await getSession({req: _req})
    logger.debug( "current session: ", session )
    const accessToken = session?.accessToken ?? "";
    const query = {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'infraToken': session.infraToken
            // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
        referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
        body: JSON.stringify({
            operationName: _req.body.operationName,
            variables: _req.body.variables,
            query: _req.body.query
        }) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    };
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/graphql', query)
    const json = await res.json()
    _res.statusCode = 200;
    _res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    _res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=180000');
    _res.json(json)
    _res.end()
};
```

> I have other endpoints to address rest operations such as image upload
> and fetching. And authentication respectively under
> /api/rest/[...rest].js and /api/auth/[...nextauth].js